# Read in positive numbers from the user until they enter a negative number. Print out the largest positive number that was read. Java

Tags: java

So like, I'm new to Java and whatnot and for the most part, it's been pretty alright. However, I'm kind of stumped with this one problem. So basically I have to write a program in a conditional loop where it reads user input: You enter positive numbers until you enter a negative number, where the program then prints out the largest positive number in that.

I'm building this off of another program where the program read in positive numbers until you entered a negative one in which the program would then print out the sum.

I don't really know what to do past this, can anyone help?

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter=0;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int number=sc.nextInt();
    
    while(number>=0){
      counter=counter+number;
      number=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: replace your sum by a logical condition:  if `number` is greater than `counter` therfore `counter=number` :
` if( number > counter ){ counter = number; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close ...

Create a variable to hold the largest value, then on each loop iteration check if the number entered is greater than the largest value. If so, update it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  
class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                int largest=0;
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

                int number=sc.nextInt();
                while(number>=0){
                        if (number > largest) {
                                largest = number;
                        }
                        number=sc.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println(largest);
        }
}
```

Comment: what if I wanted to do the opposite and print the smallest positive number?

Comment: Create another variable, add another if statement and print the new value. Follow the pattern in the code. You can do this.

Answer (score 0):

the quickest way to request user input off the bat, just like that, is the `prompt` function.. welcome to javascript :}

```js
var n=0;
var arr=[];
while(n!=-1){
  var m=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number\nEnter value -1 to end entries")); //parseInt attempts to turn the data input into a number and prompt returns what the user inputs
  if(!isNaN(m)){//i'm asking if m is a number
    if(m!=-1){arr.push(m);}//this ensures that when -1 is inputted, it isn't a part of the values sorted through
    n=m;
  }
}
alert(arr.sort().reverse()); //sort sorts from highest to lowest, reversing such would do the exact opposite
```

Comment: olol when i first saw the question he wanted to translate it to javascript xD